# How do I connect 2 of my curves together?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have been making a lap time simulator where the body does not accelerated longitudinally but only in the straights. I have the acceleration of both the body in the straight line and in the turn however I want to connect them together so it looks like a regular graph.

The code in question is as follows

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

g = 9.81  # Gravity
pa = 1.2  # Air density
m = 250  # mass of bike
h = 0.69  # centre of mass height
ha = 0.69  # height of centre pressure
w = 1.5  # wheelbase
b = 0.73  # longitudinal distance of centre of mass
CdA = 0.2  # drag coefficient
PMax = 180000  # max power
ux = 1.2  # Longitudinal friction coefficient
uy = 1.44  # Lateral friction coefficient

T8_Angle = 180
T8_Radius = 80.5352283/2
T8_Length = T8_Radius * (T8_Angle*(np.pi/180))

T8_Velo = np.sqrt(uy*g*T8_Radius)

St1Length = 400

dsa1 = 1
vela1 = [T8_Velo]
sa1 = [0.]

while sa1[-1] < St1Length:
    Fd = 0.5 * pa * CdA * vela1[-1]**2
    Ap = ((PMax / ((m * vela1[-1]) + 1e-9)) - (Fd / m)) / g  
    yw = 0
    Aw = (((b * np.sqrt((yw)**2 + g**2)) / h) - ((Fd * ha) / (m * h))) / g
    Wheelie_Min = np.minimum(Ap, Aw)
    vela1_new = np.sqrt(vela1[-1]**2 + 2*Wheelie_Min*dsa1*g)
    vela1.append(vela1_new)

    sa1_new = sa1[-1] + dsa1 
    sa1.append(sa1_new)


T1_Angle = 90
T1_Length = 315
T1_Radius = T1_Length/(2*np.pi*(T1_Angle/360))

T1_Velo = np.sqrt(uy*g*T1_Radius)

dsd1 = 1
veld1 = [T1_Velo]
sd1 = [St1Length]

while sd1[-1] > 0:
    Fd = 0.5 * pa * CdA * veld1[-1]**2
    yw = 0
    Ad = (((g * ux * (np.sqrt(1 - (((yw)/ g)**2) * (1 / uy**2))) + (Fd / m))) * -1) / g  
    As = ((((w-b) * np.sqrt((yw)**2 + g**2)) / h) + ((Fd * ha) / (m *h))) / (g *-1)
    Deceleration_Max = np.maximum(Ad, As)
    veld1_new = np.sqrt(veld1[-1]**2 - 2*Deceleration_Max*g*dsd1)
    veld1.append(veld1_new)

    sd1_new = sd1[-1] - dsd1 
    sd1.append(sd1_new)

min_vel1 = []
for i in range(len(sa1)):
    s1 = sa1[i]
    v1_1 = vela1[i]
    v2_1 = veld1[-i-1]
    min_v1 = min(v1_1, v2_1)
    min_vel1.append(min_v1)


time1 = [0]
for i in range(1, len(sa1)):
    time1.append(time1[i-1] + (sa1[i] - sa1[i-1]) / min_vel1[i-1])

acc1 = [0]
for i in range(1, len(sa1)):
    Time_Diff1 = time1[i] - time1[i-1]
    Velo_Diff1 = min_vel1[i] - min_vel1[i-1]
    acc1.append(Velo_Diff1/Time_Diff1)

St1Last = sa1[-1]
St1T1 = St1Last+T1_Length
fig, lv = plt.subplots()
lv.plot(sa1, acc1, 'b')
lv.hlines(0, St1Last, St1T1, 'b')

plt.xlabel('Distance (s)')
plt.ylabel('Acceleration (m/s)')
```

and the graph looks like this
[image]

Any help would be gladly appreciated

Comment: Why not just add your additional points to the end of `sa1` and `acc1`?

Comment: @TimRoberts Thank you for the idea! I just changed it so I extended my acc1 into an array of 0's and extended my sa1 array but added sda1 until St1T1